# Extraction version from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I have a file `file1` which looks as below
`version=7.2.3.cdead_rcd345`

I am using the following command but it is not working
`cat file1 | awk -F'=' '{print $2}`

It is not giving the version number

Comment: What you expected? `7.2.3` or `7.2.3.cdead_rcd345` ?

Comment: add expected output for clarity.. and also mention how the version number is constructed.. is it always 3 numbers separated by `.` or there could be other variations too?

Answer (score 3):

**`Awk`** solution to extract version number in format `<number>.<number>[.number]`:

```
awk -F'[=_]' '{ sub(/\.[^.]*$/, "", $2); print $2 }' file1
7.2.3
```

Comment: good one.. not sure why field separator is `[=_]`, will also work with `-F=`  :)... also, if gensub is there, `awk -F= '{ print gensub(/\.[^.]*$/, "", 1, $2) }'`

Comment: @Sundeep, I've decided to apply `-F'[=_]'` because `-F'='` would fail in case of such input `"version=7.2.3.cdead_rcd3.45"`. However, the OP still haven't elaborated his version number format

Comment: oh ok, but that assumes presence of `_` in input, which may not be true for other cases.. so, OP definitely has to clarify such things :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need only `7.2.3` as answer, try `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/.*=(.*)\..*/\1/g' file1
```

Outpt:

```
7.2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing one `'` in the end of your command:

`awk -F"=" '{print $2}' file1`

Output:

`7.2.3.cdead_rcd345wq`

Comment: the `cat` and the `pipe` are pointless...  you can use `awk` directly

Comment: but I think the desired output should be more clearer, whether it should be only `7.2.3` or `7.2.3.cdead_rcd345wq`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following commands:

1. `awk`  **without** the `cat`, since it is pointless here

**command:**

```
awk -F'=' '{print $2}' file1
```

**output:**

```
7.2.3.cdead_rcd345wq
```

2. or **even better** use `grep` directly:

**command:**

```
grep -Po '(?<=version=).*' file1
```

**output:**

```
7.2.3.cdead_rcd345wq
```

**test:**

[image]

Last but not least, if you need only the **version number (7.2.3)** than you can use the following command:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=version=)\d\.\d\.\d' file1
7.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grep "version" in the file, split the line by "=", and get the second word. This method is very easy to understand.

```
grep "version" file1 | cut -d "=" -f 2
```